# Force las=1 on a global level for plot axis

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

Some plot functions of many packages do not accept the `las=1` as an argument, nor do they allow `yaxt="n"` and then drawing with `axis()`.

Is it possible to force `las=1` and set it as plotting default on a global level?

Comment: PLease provide specific examples and sample code. Are these plot **functions** or **methods**, for example?

Comment: `las` is a global [graphical parameter](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/par.html), so you should be able to set it with `par(las=1)`, which will be followed unless specific functions override it atomically (or by a subsequent call to `par`).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft My specific example was the `plot.performance` method of the ROCR package

Comment: @Thomas please make it an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`las` is a global [graphical parameter](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/par.html), so you can set it with `par(las=1)`, as you would set any other graphical parameter.

This will be respected on subsequent plots unless specific functions override it atomically or by a subsequent call to `par`.